# How to pipe stdin into mysql parameter

Tags: linux, mysql

I want to try and import a database from an SQL file. I want to supply the argument for the `--defaults-extra-file` parameter by echoing a config file and pipe the output to the command.

This command:

```
echo -e "[client]\nuser=user\npassword='mypass'\nhost=10.20.30.14\n" | mysql --defaults-extra-file=/dev/stdin db-1 < db-2.sql
```

Return this error:

```
mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /dev/stdin at line 1.
mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

But I do have its group defined.
I have tried these groups `[client]`, `[mysql]` and `[mysqld]`

I also tried the `--defaults-file` parameter.

---

I do not have this same problem for the `mysqldump` command. Below command works fine:

```
echo -e "[client]\nuser=user\npassword='mypass'\nhost=10.20.30.14\n" | mysqldump --defaults-file=/dev/stdin --add-drop-table db2 -N --column-statistics=0 > db-2.sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql` (or any other command) cannot read two separate files via its stdin. The stdin is one file. Your first command is basically:

```
echo -e "…\n" | mysql … < db-2.sql
```

It's like:

```
echo foo | cat - < /etc/fstab
```

Try it. `<` "wins" over `|` in setting up where the stdin of `cat` comes from.

Your second command does not contain `<`; it contains `> db-2.sql` which redirects stdout. In this case `|` works as you expect.

Comment: That makes sense. I have split up the command to create the config file first and then use it as input. I was hoping to combine it in 1 line. Thank you!